# Rating icon doesn't show in my Angular project

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning Angular by following a book and i came to a task where i have to implement a rating component using bootstrap.When i compile my code, the rating component doesn't appear and I couldn't find the mistake...

**rating.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: "rating",
    template:`<i
    class="glyphicon"
    [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="rating < 1"
    [class.glyphicon-star]="rating >= 1"
    (click)="onClick(1)"
    >
    </i>
    `
})

export class RatingComponent{
    rating = 0;
onClick(ratingValue:any){
this.rating = ratingValue;
}
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <rating></rating>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular Project';
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ProductsComponent } from './Components/product.component';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdvertisementComponent } from './Components/advertisement.component';
import { MaterialComponent } from './Components/material.component';
import { RatingComponent } from './Components/rating.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,ProductsComponent,AdvertisementComponent,MaterialComponent,RatingComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use glyphicon in Bootstrap5, it was discontinued in Bootstrap4.

If you really want to use glyphicon and if working with an older version of Bootstrap it's not a problem, you can use Bootstrap3 changing the index.html file

```
 <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 />
```

Your code is displaying only one star, you can show 5 stars changing the template to something like:

```
<span *ngFor="let number of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]">
  <i
    class="glyphicon"
    [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="rating < number"
    [class.glyphicon-star]="rating >= number"
    (click)="onClick(number)"
  >
  </i>
</span>
```

Comment: it worked but it only displayed one star.. is that by default or should i change something in code to make it display 5 stars?

Comment: @Lajibolala I edited my answer, this change worked fine here to show 5 stars